# How to set vertical mark in bash

Tags: bash, tags

I would like to mark a **vertical** position in bash shell.

For example, when I run a programm, I would like to set a mark in the first lines printed, so that when I worked (still under the shell), I just have to press several keys to see the first results of my programm. Think about it the VIM way, you set a mark above the current line (pressing `ma`), and when you worked a little bit, when you want to see what you previously do you just type `'a`.

To be more specific, I run a programm under gdb who gives results over numerous lines. Then I run tests, still in gdb, and I want to check regularly if what I get during debug is still corresponding to the first printed results I got, but I'm not really fond of scrolling up indefinitely.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Do you mean in the *terminal* history or in the Bash history?

Comment: I mean the stdout output, what is printed out in your terminal.
To be more specific, I run a programm under gdb who gives results. Then I run tests, still in gdb, and I want to check regularly if what I get during debug is still corresponding to the first lines I got.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **compare two runs of the same command**, make sure you save the first to a file:

```
$ command > command.log
```

Then pipe the output of the second command to `tee` to show and save it at the same time:

```
$ command | tee command2.log
```

Now you can diff the two while the second command is running:

```
$ diff command.log command2.log
```

(You may want to pipe the `diff` output to for example `head` to cut off the possibly large diff resulting from the second command not yet having finished.)

If you're trying to **get back to something *printed* in the terminal history** while it's still open, then in several terminals you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to find text.

If you want to **find your Bash commands** later in time, you can use comments to add tags:

```
$ my_complicated_remote_command # ssh server thingie
```

Now you can search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> for "ssh" or "thingie", and the old command comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ctrl-Shift-f would have done the trick but I don't have such feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can run TMUX and set mode-keys to vi:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

Thereafter when you enter copy mode (default is: Ctrl + B) you can use vi bindings to jump around. You can definitely jump to a specific line number and search text but I haven't seen vi mark's working just yet.